# I am trying to customize the Error format for Rest API with spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, rest

Below is syntax of the code. It is throwing compilation error java: `cannot infer type arguments for org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<>`

Can any one suggest how to fix this error please?

@ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorResponse>> process(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Arrays.asList(generateErrorResponse(ex, request)), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    private ErrorResponse generateErrorResponse(ValidationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorResponse error = new ErrorResponse();
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        error.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        error.setError(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, NOT_FOUND.value());


       /* return new ErrorResponse(
                ex.ge,
                ex.getErrorCode(),
                message,
                request.getContextPath()
        );*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error messages tells you not to use type arguments, to avoid them. Try

```
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse[]>
```

instead of

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorResponse>>
```